# How to specify what object is null in a method call?

Tags: java, null, overloading

I'm making Spigot/Bukkit plugins for Minecraft, and I came across an ambiguous method call, which for one of the parameters I want to be null.

Is there any way I can specify which method I want to use or which object I'm saying is null?

Thanks.

Comment: Cast `null` to the desired object type, like `(String) null`. [DEMO](http://ideone.com/FVOpV9)

Comment: *Objects* can never be null. *Variables* can, but never objects. Please clarify your question, as I'm not sure if what you want to do is to cast your null to some type or not,... e.g., `foo((SomeType) null);`

Comment: Yeah, thanks. It's a Set<Object>, and casting it did the trick. Thanks!